# Google Extensions запуск скрипта

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Я искал, но так и не нашел, что-то похожее на мою проблему. Вопрос в том, как запускать скрипт в какой-либо промежуток времени. К примеру, наступает 12:00 запускается скрипт выполняет свой код, засыпает на час, наступает 13:00 и так с промежутком в час.

Comment: Сделайте background скрипт и в нем используйте стандартный setTimeout для планирования выполнения функции через заданное время

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам не требуется запускать скрипт чаще чем раз в минуту, то вам отлчино подойдет встроенно API [chrome.alarms](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/alarms). 
В сочетании [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) с датами будет работать еще проще.

P.S. Учтите, что у некоторых пользователей время на компьютере сбито и не является правильным. Если требуется именно настоящее, то за ним необходимо будет ходить на некий свой сервер.

Comment: спасибо это помогло